# Quick Karate POST request advice

Tags: karate

I'm attempting to send a simple POST request and struggling slightly.

Postman data request shown
    --data-raw '""'

```
Given url TESTURL
And request '""'
When method post 
Then status 200
```

A 500 response is returned every time, this works in postman. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a header

```
* header Content-Type = 'text/plain'
```

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately. The content type of the request is sent as an application/json

Comment: @Goku5 follow this process. if we can replicate it we can fix it. else you are on your own: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue